# Customise Freedesktop file with sbt-native-packager and JDKPackager plugin

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

I would like to customize the `.desktop` file created by the javapackager as part of the JDKPackager plugin of sbt-native-packager. It obviously uses a template:

```
[info]   Using default package resource [Menu shortcut descriptor]
         (add package/linux/Foo.desktop to the class path to customize)
```

In particular, I want to add the `StartupWMClass` entry that will be used by Gnome to unify all the windows opened by my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javapackager refers to the target directory of the plugin, i.e. `target/jdkpackager`. This is created for example when the javafx-ant build-file is written. So we can piggyback here:

```
// rewrite the task so that after the ant build is created,
// we add package/linux/MyApp.desktop
writeAntBuild in JDKPackager := {
  val res  = (writeAntBuild in JDKPackager).value
  val main = (mainClass     in JDKPackager).value
    .getOrElse(sys.error("No main class specified"))
  val tgt  = (target        in JDKPackager).value
  val n    = (name          in JDKPackager).value
  val wm   = main.replace('.', '-')
  val desktop = 
    s"""[Desktop Entry]
       |Name=APPLICATION_NAME
       |Comment=APPLICATION_SUMMARY
       |Exec=/opt/APPLICATION_FS_NAME/APPLICATION_LAUNCHER_FILENAME
       |Icon=/opt/APPLICATION_FS_NAME/APPLICATION_LAUNCHER_FILENAME.png
       |Terminal=false
       |Type=Application
       |Categories=DEPLOY_BUNDLE_CATEGORY
       |DESKTOP_MIMES
       |StartupWMClass=$wm
       |""".stripMargin
  IO.write(tgt / "package" / "linux" / s"$n.desktop", desktop)
  res
}
```

Comment: The reason this works, which isn't entirely obvious from the Oracle `javapackager` documentation, is that the `build.xml` file puts the `tgt` directory in the Ant task classpath, which then looks for override resources in the `package/linux` branch of its classpath.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a corresponding setting in the [Ant task XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html), there is an alternative solution: **just rewriting the XML generated by the plugin, via `antBuildDefn`**, will suffice.

Here's an example of specifying a menu category for the `.desktop` file, via adding the [`category` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIAIEJHG) :

```
antBuildDefn in JDKPackager := {
  val origTask = (antBuildDefn in JDKPackager).value

  val InfoLabel = "info"
  val KeyRegex  = s"$InfoLabel\\.(.+)".r

  import scala.xml._
  import scala.xml.transform._
  val infoRewrite = new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: Node) = n match {
      case e: Elem if e.prefix == "fx" && e.label == InfoLabel =>
        e % Attribute("", "category", "Office", Null)
      case other => other
    }
  }

  new RuleTransformer(infoRewrite)(origTask)
}
```